# How to set up a new workstation after adding .gitignore to the repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, gitignore

I have a deployed rails website, and have a gitignore file in place.  If I pull the app to a new computer or workstation, none of the gitignore files will be there since they are being igrnored.  How do I correctly set up a new workstation?  Do I just copy the files from another location and place them in the correct folders on the new workstation?

Comment: Of course none of the ignored files will be in the repository, that's the whole purpose of the `.gitignore` file. What did you expect?

Comment: That's exactly what I expected.  But now I'd just like to know the best practice for setting up a new workstation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those files you specified in the .gitignore are an essential part of your website configuration, they should be in the repository and not ignored.

Answer (score 3):

What some like to do, including myself, is to add example configuraton to the repo. For instance, you'd add `database.yml` to the gitignore so that nobody commits their personal passwords and then create a `database.example.yml` file that contains an example of how to set up `database.yml`

Comment: I think I've just made a mistake.  I added /db/*.sqlite3 to my gitignore, when in fact I should have not added /db/development.sqlite3 since I need to have some sample data inputted into the database for it to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Ignore files for **everyone cloning the project**
   This is done using the file **.gitignore** in any folder of your git repository (people usually use one .gitignore at the root folder of the repository). The "ignore-behaviour" will be transmitted to everyone cloning or pulling the repository if you run `git add .gitignore`, commit and push.
2. Ignore files **only for you, and only in this repository**
   This is done by using the same syntax as in the .gitignore, but in the file **.git/info/exclude**. The "ignore-behaviour" won't be transmitted to anyone, and only applies to you and to this specific repository.
3. Ignore files **only for you, for all of your repositories**
   You can do this by defining a user .gitignore with
   `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`.
4. Ignore files **for all users on this computer, and for all of the repositories**
   You can do this with a system-wide .gitignore: `sudo git config --system core.excludesfile /etc/gitignore`

I personally intensively use 1 and 2 (the file `.git/info/exclude` can really be useful sometimes), but never the 3 and 4.